# SVG generator to generate exact shape by tracing it in an image?

Tags: html, svg, generator

I am looking for a SVG generator where I can draw a shape in an image (trace)by adding points or something similar and then save that exact shape as SVG. I found some generators but they generate the whole image, which is not what I want.

Say I have an image with a circle inside. I want to trace that circle and save only that shape as SVG shape, not the rest of the image.

Know any links for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the online tool [here](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html)

You can add an image onto a single layer. And then create a new layer for drawing on top of the image. Once you are done, delete the image layer and export the rest as an SVG

**Update:**
Looks like the project has moved to github. Updated link [here](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html)

Comment: The tools looks good but it acts funny. I choose the pen tool and click for example, and the click shows up WAY below where I actually clicked, I can't even see it on the screen because I have to scroll down. I cannot trace an image like this. Any idea how to make it behave normally?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Can you try a different browser? I'm currently using the latest version of chrome

Comment: Yes, I used firefox and it works good in Chrome! This tool is great!

Comment: @IzaazYunus link is broken. what's the name of the tool so we can check if it still exists?

Comment: Updated the link @cr0ss

Comment: The tool is great. The first link doesn't work, but the updated link is pure nectar. To save changes, click "Apply Changes" at the top-left area. It will generate the SVG code.